# Das ist eine unsere Stärken vs unserer Stärken

Tags: possessive-pronoun

> Das ist eine **unsere** Stärken.
>   Das ist eine **unserer** Stärken.

Which is correct? And why?

Can someone please explain it to me (in English :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differently said, and shorter ;-) :

The sentence "Dies ist eine unserer Stärken" is in fact the shortened version of: "Dies ist eine Stärke unserer Stärken."

Now, let's say the long version with a preposition: "Dies ist eine Stärke **von** (+ D.) unser**en** Stärke**n**." -> Dies ist eine von unseren Stärken.

Let us now replace "**von** (+ D.) unser**en** Stärke**n**" by a genitive, and we get: "Dies ist eine unser**er** Stärke**n**".

Your problem is that in "Dies ist eine *unsere Stärken" we would either have three nominative forms (*dies*; *eine*; *unsere Stärken*) or a two nominatives (*dies*; *eine*) + an accusative (*unsere Stärken*). Neither of these constructions exists, grammatically and logically, as this *one strength* is **part of** *several strengths*. That's what we call genitivus parti**ti**vus, and that's it. :-))

Comment: "Dies ist eine Stärke unserer Stärken" is nonsensical. There is no need to claim that a noun is missing in "Dies ist eine unserer Stärken".

Comment: Wenn du in den Seminaren zur generativen Transformationsgrammatik besser aufgepasst hättest, oder wenigstens im Deutsch- und Lateinunterricht in der Schule, dann wüsstest du, aus welcher Tiefenstruktur die vorliegende Oberflächenstruktur generiert wurde bzw. dass es Ellipsen gibt. Deshalb ist hier gar nichts 'nonsensical'.

Aus seiner Sicht ist Trump der größte Präsident aller Präsidenten. -> Aus seiner Sicht ist Trump der größte Ø aller Präsidenten.

Aus seiner Sicht ist Trump der größte Präsident von allen Präsidenten. -> Aus seiner Sicht ist Trump der größte Präsident von allen Ø.

Comment: Wenn die Antwort auf Annahmen aus der Transformationsgrammatik basiert, solltest du das erwähnen. Interessanterweise tritt, wenn man anstelle von "Stärke" ein maskulines oder neutrales Nomen setzt, eine Form auf, die aufgrund der Endung eindeutig als Pronomen und nicht als Artikel zu identifizieren ist, was der Annahme der Weglassung eines Nomens widerspricht: "Dies ist einer unserer Vorteile", "Dies ist eins unserer Angebote".

Answer (score 4):

This is correct:

> Das ist eine unserer Stärken.
>   This is one of our strengths.

The part *»unserer Stärken«* (*of our strengths*) is in genitive case. This grammatical case is used for many circumstances, one of them is for possessive objects, i.e for objects that express some form of ownership. Here we are talking about one specific strength, that belongs to (is owned by) a group of other strengths *(which again belongs to a person (i.e. to us) but this kind of ownership is not important for the choice of genitive case).*

If something is part of something else, and when you express this ownership with genitive case, then you call this specific usage of genitive case:

- **genitivus partitivus** = Genitive case for a group of which something else is a part.

  > Michael ist der Leiter **der Gruppe.** Michael is the leader **of the group.**
  >   Walter hat zwei **der Gemälde** verkauft. Walter has sold two **of the paintings.**
  >   Du kannst nur mit einer **meiner Töchter** ausgehen. You can only date one **of my daughters.**

So, now it should be clear, that you have to use genitive case here.

Most objects are not just one word, but a small group of word, one of them a noun. Here the object consists of two words:

- a form of the possessive pronoun *»unser«*
- a form of the feminine noun *»die Stärke«*

This group must be transformed into plural and into genitive case.

If you are unsure, you can look up inflection tables:

- [https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stärke](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/St%C3%A4rke)
  On this site you will find:
  **Genitive plural of *»die Stärke«* is *»der Stärken«*.**
- https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/unser
  There are two homonyms of *»unser«*. One of them is a personal pronoun, but this is not what we we are talking about here. To see the other one (the possessive pronoun) you need to scroll down. And then you will see:
  **Feminine genitive plural of *»unser«* is *»unserer«*.**
  There is also the form *»unsrer«*, but is a rare. You use it in poems and lyrics when you need a word with two syllables (uns-rer). The standard form is *»unserer«* which has three syllables (uns-er-er).

So, the genitive object must be:

> unserer Stärken (standard form)
>   unsrer Stärken (alternative form)

And the complete sentence:

> Das ist eine unserer Stärken. (standard)
>   Das ist eine unsrer Stärken. (sometimes in lyrics, poems, etc.)